# Is it possible to define "fields" attribute of <apex:remoteObjects> without hardcoding its values?

Tags: visualforce, remote-objects

Is it possible to include these fields `Id,Name,Description__c` in a Remote Objects definition within a Visualforce Page ***without*** hardcoding them? I would like to pass them from elsewhere and am exploring how to do that.

```
<apex:remoteObjects >
<apex:remoteObjectModel jsShortHand="rObjModelJsSH" name="customObject__c" fields="Id,Name,Description__c">            
    <apex:remoteObjectField name="relationship__c" jsShorthand="Parent" />
</apex:remoteObjectModel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious way to try this is to set the `fields` list to a Visualforce expression. Unfortunately, although that *does* compile, it doesn't work:

```
<apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="Test">
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Account" fields="{! fieldList }">            
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

You get back the `Id` only when you perform a retrieve.

However, you can do this with a [remote objects action override](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_override_actions.htm).

### Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="TestRemoteActionOverrideController">
    <apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="Test">
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Account" fields="Id"
                                retrieve="{! $RemoteAction.TestRemoteActionOverrideController.retrieve }" />            
    </apex:remoteObjects>
    <script>
        var act = new Test.Account();
        act.retrieve(
            { },
            function(error, results, event) {
                alert('Got results: ' + JSON.stringify(results) + ' Error was: ' + error);
            }
        );
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

### Apex Controller

```
public class TestRemoteActionOverrideController{
    @RemoteAction
    public static Map<String,Object> retrieve(String type, List<String> fields, Map<String, Object> criteria) {
        fields.add('Name');

        // call through to the default remote object controller with our modified field list.
        return RemoteObjectController.retrieve(type, fields, criteria);
    }
}
```

If you load this page, you'll find both the `Name` and `Id` fields populated in the alert message. You can, if necessary, override other remote actions accordingly.